# Manipulate parts of html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html I have a (hidden) template, something like

```
<div class="tabletemplate dontshow" >
   <p class="movieFile"></p>
   <p class="movieDirector"></p>
</div>
```

I obtain the template by

```
var tableTemplate = $(".tabletemplate").clone().removeClass("dontshow");
```

I then want to insert text strings into the template. I tried a few things like

```
tableTemplate.find(".movieFile").text(movieInfo.FileName);
```

or

```
$(".movieFile", tableTemplate).text(movieInfo.FileName);
```

but none seem to work.

How can I do that easily, ideally without having to learn an entire new js library.

Comment: after inserting the text file... did you append the cloned element back to the dom

Comment: After cloning you need to insert that tableTemplate somewhere.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vQH3v/2/

Comment: Yes, I convert the template to a text string that then will be inserted into a table I create on the fly. That all works. I checked with firebug. The template is fine, movieInfo.FileName has a string and I can create the table from the templates just fine. I just cannot get a string into the template before I create the table

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for that is function appendTo:

```
$(".movieFile").appendTo(movieInfo.FileName);
```

or

```
tableTemplate.find(".movieFile").appendTo(movieInfo.FileName);
```

Comment: Could you please give me that solution in the context of my code? I am very new to jquery.

Comment: $(".movieFile").appendTo(movieInfo.FileName);

Comment: no. the tableTemplate is unchanged. I will continue with this in a few hours and then report.

Comment: Ok, im quite sure that you have use appendTo, I have done something similar few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".tabletemplate").clone().removeClass("dontshow").appendTo(".tabletemplate");
var movieFile = $(".tabletemplate").find(".movieFile")[0];
$(movieFile).text(movieInfo.FileName);
```

Works for me. You would have to change the last appendTo class to the parent of tabletemplate ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had it right all along, except that my `movieInfo.FileName` object doesn't work for some reason, although firebug shows me the correct string. I have to work on that some more. Replacing it with text constants showed me that I was on the right track...
It turned out I didn't need `"append"` or `"appendTo"`.

Here's what I have and it works:

```
    jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function () {
        return (this[0]) ? this[0].outerHTML : '';
    };

    function createTableElement(movieInfo) {
        var template = tableTemplate.clone();

        // template.find(".movieFile").text(movieInfo.FileName);
        template.find(".movieFile").text("the movie");
        template.find(".movieDirector").text("the director");
        return template.outerHTML();
    }
```

This function returns the html string of the entire `div` which I then can use to construct my table

Thank you all for your help and the very quick responses!